# JButton Array Action Listener work for the last button only

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I made a button array and tried to add an ActionListener to each button in a for loop and also listen to all the button using a for loop but the thing is that the only responding button is the last one created. What am I doing wrong?

```
nums = new JButton[13];
ListenForButton lfb = new ListenForButton();
for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
    nums[i].addActionListener(lfb);
}
```

---

```
private class ListenForButton implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for(int i=0;i<13;i++){
            if( e.getSource() == nums[i]) {
                System.out.println("pressed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you be populating each element of your `nums` array with a `new JButton()` first?

Comment: yes i done that (this is not the full code)

Comment: @alaslipknot, post your SSCCE that demonstrates the problem. We can't guess what your code is actually like.

Comment: @camickr
here is it [link](http://www.sourcepod.com/jfzyun92-17643) 
sorry i couldn't write here
the problem is with the switch statement cause when i create a "simple" array of button everything works fine

Comment: weird ... 
i changed the switch statement with a bunch of "else if" and everything works fine

Comment: @alaslipknot, post your code with your question, not on another website.

Answer (score 1):

Method ActionEvent.getSource() returns an instance of type Object, you need to typecast it to JButton for this

```
if( e.getSource() == nums[i])
```

to be true, so do this instead of the above statement:

```
if( ((JButton)e.getSource()) == nums[i])
```

Also try this:

```
nums = new JButton[13];

for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) 
 {
    nums[i] = new JButton();
    nums[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
       {
           System.out.println("pressed");
       }
    });
 }
```

or use ActionCommand, like this:

```
nums = new JButton[13];

ListenerForButton lfb = new ListenerForButton();
for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) 
 {
    nums[i] = new JButton();
    nums[i].setActionCommand("button"+i);
    nums[i].addActionListener(lfb);
 }

 private class ListenForButton implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        for(int i=0;i<13;i++){

        if( e.getActionCommand().equals("button"+i)) {
               System.out.println("pressed" + i); //for  getting which button is actually clicked
           }
    }
```

Comment: i don't want to use the listener inside the same for loop, i prefer using another class, is there any way to do that ?

Comment: The way you're doing it is also fine, please typecast return value of getSource and tell me if works for you?

Comment: i tried that, also, it only works with the last button and the i value is always equal to 1

Comment: Can you please check it now?I've edited my answer, I've used action command now

Comment: thank you very much for your help, i think the problem is not there, 
after creating the buttons, i made another for loop just for test
for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
   System.out.println(nums[i].getText());
  } 
and it prints out the last button text only

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call nums[i].addActionListener(new ListenForButton());
In order to get a new listener for every button

Comment: And by the way. Your first for-loop is falsely indexed! Start at zero!

Comment: You don't need to create a new listener for every button. It is better to create a generic listener when the functionality for all the buttons is basically the same. For example when creating buttons for a calculator the code for adding a digit to the display is the same for digist 0...9. That is why you use an action command. The action command contains the actual digit to display but the listener is shared by all 10 buttons.